# A question on inverse functions

Tags: functions

Let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is a strictly increasing function and $f^{-1}$ is its inverse function. It satisfies:

> $f(x_1)+x_1=a$; $f^{-1}(x_2)+x_2=a$.

What is the value of $x_1+x_2$? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hint: Write $x_2=f(x_3)$: What follows about $x_3$? And what follows if you take strict monotonicity into account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the following. Since the function $f$ is strictly increasing, then  the functions $f^{-1}$ and $g(x)=f(x)+x$ are strictly increasing too. We have $a=g(x_1)=g(f^{-1}(x_2))$. Then $x_1=f^{-1}(x_2)$ and $x_1+x_2=f^{-1}(x_2)+x_2=a$.